# viadeo share doesn't consider all parameters

Tags: share, viadeo

I use the url http://www.viadeo.com/shareit/share/?title=title&overview=description&url=url

The parameters title and overview seems to be never used.

It seems that viadeo parses the url page content and use the <title> and <meta name="description" /> tags to display their contents.

Is the url http://www.viadeo.com/shareit/share/ still relevant ?

Are there some special meta tags like <meta property="og:title" /> and <meta property="og:description" /> for viadeo share ?

What's the user agent bot for viadeo ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Related to https://partners.viadeo.com/widgets/share : "Viadeo uses the embed.ly service to extract metadata from your page.
The page must be public, couldn't be localhost nor internal networks."

Embedly is the user agent bot.

Embedly will set the title response attribute to the open_graph, meta, or twitter title if available in the page. Accepted values: (og, twitter, meta)

With description Embedly will set the description response attribute to the open_graph, meta, or twitter description if available in the page. Accepted values: (og, twitter, meta)